# SAPUI5 OPA5 Testing. Diff suppressed as the expected and actual results have an equivalent serialization

Tags: testing, automated-tests, sapui5

```
Script error.@ 0 ms
Expected:   
null
Message:    Diff suppressed as the expected and actual results have an equivalent serialization
Source:     
:0
```

This is happening when at the end of the an OPA5 journey, when all tests have completed successfully.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You assert two result objects which looks like the same. But the pointer do not point to the same object.

You did not provide code for your assertion... A fast fix would be to stringify by yourself and assert the strings. Or use the correct assertion to compare objects.

See [also](https://dev.to/michalbryxi/diff-suppressed-as-the-expected-and-actual-results-have-an-equivalent-serialization-3kep)

Comment: assertions: {
     theTitleShouldDisplayTheId: function (sName) {
      return this.waitFor({
       success: function () {
        return this.waitFor({
         id: "objectHeader",
         viewName: sViewName,
         matchers: new Properties({
          text: sName
         }),
         success: function (oPage) {
          Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Product successfully displayed");
         },
         errorMessage: "The Post " + sName + " is not shown"
        });
       }
      });
     }
    }

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, matching 2 different objects that have the same value....  I've setup everything as opa5 test using the wait for, matcher, ok assertion. These all work, but the error displays after the teardown.

Comment: It really doesn't matter when the assertion fails. imo opa is a bad testing framework we stopped using it a long time ago... Anyhow change your assertion and it will work.